# How to fix a lot of unit tests when results are changed

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, resharper

I use Visual Studio with Resharper and NUnit test framework.

Sometimes a small change in business logic code breaks a lot of unittests. It's OK, you know that the results of unittests would be different and new values are valid now. Is there a way to quick-fix all of them?

[image: Broken tests]

Comment: Why are you even testing the same thing in these many unit tests? Do they are unit tests are integration tests? If former, it shouldn't fail these many. If it does, you're testing same thing over and over. Don't do that.

Comment: Yeap, you're right, this tests should be called integration tests from this point of view

Comment: I think this is more a problem of customer management than code. I mean if you implemented an automatic 'updated expected values' program, how would you check it? your tests should ultimately rely on a human at some point saying, 'yes, this is the result we want' I suggest you set up the calc in a spreadsheet, you can use this to product a large set of result values and confirm with the customer they are happy with them. and then export to a csv of parameters and expected results for a data driven unit test

Comment: I would be very wary of allowing tooling to update unit test expected values. Expected values should come from subject matter experts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually there is no solution for quick-fix expected values. If your changes break a lot of integration tests, you have to manually correct all of tests.

The only hint is to minimize distance between copy-paste operations of expected values.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the various refactor tools which come with VS to make (small) changes to your code that are not a result of a change in business logic. Examples of this are renaming variables and functions or moving code to a different namespace.
Especially when you use ReSharper, there are lots of options that will help you to refactor code. (Resharper menu > Refactor).

If you are changing the business logic of your application then the software requirements must have changed. Therefore the unit tests that apply to that logic *should* fail and there is no way to automagically correct this.

Comment: I speak about business logic changes. I wrote all of that tests before and now our customer said: "Let's increase all values by 10%" and that breaks every test that I wrote before. New values are now valid, but that's not last change in business logic and I'm trying to find quick way to fix tests in such situations.

Comment: The good news is that your unit tests work pretty well then :)
To be prepared for this in general terms, it's good practice to extract the '10% increased value' if it's a value that is likely to change in the future. In the _Arrange_ step of your unit test, you can fetch the value in a method that you use in all your unit tests.

Comment: The '10% increased value' was for example only :)